# Flutter future to future

Tags: flutter

i have to do something in my app that technically is not that complicated but i dont know how to do it.

I need to get some data from firebase and than use that data to get other data from fireabse.

It works like that. I have an organization and from that i get only the UID of the users. After i print all the organization (only the UIDS) i than have to call the database again and get the names of the people using the uids i got earlier.

Here is what i tried doing

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: databaseReference.once(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot < DataSnapshot > snapshot) {
    List lists = [];
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      lists.clear();
      Map < dynamic, dynamic > values = snapshot.data.value;
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        lists.add(values);
        print(values);
      }, );
      return new ListView.builder(
        primary: false,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12, bottom: 15, ),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: lists.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

HERE I TRY TO CALL IT AGAIN WITH THE REZULT I GET
          FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users/" + lists[index]["UID"].toString() + "/Name").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
            aa = snapshot.value;
          });


          return Container(
            child: Text("$aa"));
        });
    }
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
        child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }),
```

The problem i get is that it gets delayed null appears if i show that in the container and it wont appear. I was thinking of adding a future builder inside that future builder. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could handle all the users fetch inside a Future/Stream Provider and simplify your Widget, just presenting the list of Users?

Example:

```
class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AsyncValue<List<User>> asyncUsers = useProvider(allUsersProvider);
    return asyncUsers.when(
      data: (users) => ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: users.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
          child: Text(users[index].name),
        ),
      ),
      loading: () => Text('Loading...'),
      error: (error, trace) => Text('Something bad happened'),
    );
  }
}
```